# How to Create interruptible loop in mel

Tags: loops, mel

Is there a way to make a loop which can be interrupted or cancelled in MEL (Maya Embedded Language)?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a progress bar. Example straight from the manual:

```
{
    global string $gMainProgressBar;  // This is defined on maya startup

    progressBar -edit
        -beginProgress
        -isInterruptable true
        -status "Example Calculation ..."
        -maxValue 5000
        $gMainProgressBar;

    int $i;
    for($i=0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
        if(`progressBar -query -isCancelled $gMainProgressBar`)
            break;

        progressBar -edit
            -step 1 $gMainProgressBar; 
    }

    progressBar -edit
        -endProgress
        $gMainProgressBar;
}
```

Maya now shows progress and allows you to use *esc* to interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` instruction. For example:

```
string $joints[] = {"joint1","joint2","joint3","joint4","joint5","joint6"};
for ($i = 0; $i < size($joints); $i++) {
    if ($i > 3){
        break;
    }
    print $joints[$i];
}
```

will print only first 4 elements: joint1 joint2 joint3 joint4

Comment: It is always easy to break of the loop via a condition. I want to get escaped the loop once the loop starts. This is because the loop should start and get finished by taking all the elements into consideration, incase in this process if the user wish to stop the loop it should be able to do so. Hope I am able to make my point clear.